# Blender 2.8. Hotkey for selecting transform manipulators

Tags: 3d-view, transforms

[image: Manipulators]

How to bind hotkeys to transform manipulator in Blender 2.80?

I want to customize them like in Maya, but i can't find them in input tab

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This feature is not implemented in Blender 2.80 Alpha 2